# How to close all open terminal windows except the one running a shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I wanted to have a script that is capable of killing console windows, that are either running something or not, but at the same time, keep alive the window that executed this script.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Originally posted at https://askubuntu.com/questions/976247/how-to-close-all-open-terminal-windows-except-the-one-running-a-shell-script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the command name of the parent the script (bash, sh, zsh, etc.) then kill all the processes with that command-name.
This way you kill all the bash processes but the one running the script.
i.e.

```
C=$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=)
P=$(ps -p $$ -o pid=)
for p in $(pgrep $C); do
    if [ $p -ne $P ]; then
        kill $p
    fi
done
```

This is very *not* portable. If you also want to close the consoles that are running something it becomes even less portable:

```
C=$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=)
P1=$(ps -p $$ -o pid=)
P2=$(ps -p $$ -o ppid=)
echo $(pgrep $C)
for p in $(pgrep $C | tail -n +2); do
    [ $p -ne $P1 ] && [ $p -ne $P2 ] && kill -9 $p
done
```

- It will not work if the script is launched by another script or in a
  bash session within another bash session (e.g. a root session)
- It will not kill the first bash window if the Desktop Environment was
  not launched by bash (e.g. if you have the desktop environment set to
  run at startup), to address this issue, you can remove the `| tail -n +2` in the for loop.
- It will also close the console *tabs* in addition to the windows.

Comment: Hi Omcira, thanks for your reply. Question: how can I use your script? should I replace something in it?

Comment: Copy-paste it in your script, wherever you want to close all the other console windows

Comment: Hi, it works! But I also need to close consoles that are running something. Is it possible to change your script in order to do it?

Comment: Edited the answer. Beware, that this is not a portable solution, you should really study all the possible cases your script may run into before implementing.